# How to save file on client pc instead of the server pc when using tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I have a service that saves an xlsx using POI and when I save the file to the path it saves on the server pc isntead of the client pc.

Partial code from my program:

```
public static final String EXCELPATH = "C:\\SAMPLE\\REPORTS\\";

Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet 1");

filepath = EXCELPATH + "TCRKBOS_050020_" + mTodayDate;
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filepath + ".csv");
Row row;
Cell cell;

// ********* SAMPLE CELL **************** //
row = sheet.createRow(0);
cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue("REPDTE");
cell.setCellStyle(centerHeader1);

cell = row.createCell(1);
cell.setCellValue("BNKCDE");
cell.setCellStyle(centerHeader1);

conn.close();
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.flush();
fileOut.close();
```

Comment: And what are you expecting?

Comment: Save it on my client pc, currently when I access the the web app via client pc and save the excel file it saves on the server computer instead of the client's computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't save a file on the client PC. It is the browser that manages whether files are downloaded on the client PC or not.

What you can do is send the file over HTTP as your response. I am assuming you are using a Servlet here. Inside your servlet, if you want your file download to be in response to a GET request you could do something like this:

```
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
      throws ServletException, IOException {

        resp.setContentType("text/csv");
        resp.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=TCRKBOS_050020_" + mTodayDate + ".csv");

        try (OutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream()) {
            //todo: write the CSV data to the output stream
        }
    }
```